# Permanently summing a column in an Org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

In an Emacs Org-mode table, when you have a column full of integers I know you can do `C-c +` followed by `C-y` to paste the sum of the values in the column. I want to know the formula to place in the last row to *always* sum the whole column.

I've tried everything. The [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Tables) show you how to sum two columns together but not one.

Comment: The best I've been able to get is to add a highline at the top and bottom of the table and do a column formula: =vsum(@I..@II)

Comment: As an FYI, I just posted a similar question about hline targeting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689424/emacs-org-mode-spreadsheet-targeting-via-hline

This question is already getting votes and the answer may be different, so I will leave it up in the meantime.

Comment: For those wondering, use `C-c C-c` when point is at `#+TBLFM:` line to execute the forumula given in the answers.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assign a field-name using the `^` mark:

```
|---+---|
|   | 1 |
|   | 2 |
|   | 3 |
|---+---|
|   | 6 |
| ^ | x |
|---+---|
#+TBLFM: $x=vsum(@1..@-1)
```

See [*The Org Manual*, Section-3.5.9 Advanced Features](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-features).

Comment: Thanks! This ends up working pretty good and I'm fine with it, however, I do now I have a "header" hline and "footer" hline with the same things. Is there a way to this using just the header hline. In the docs its the "-" marking, but then I don't know how to use vsum(@2..@[last item]).

Comment: You can also do `#+TBLFM: @row$col=vsum(@1..@-1)`

Comment: I get `Unknown field: x`

Comment: I also got unknown field. Read the manual, basically in the above example it's calling the row above the ^ x x, so that the 6 is calculated from the vsum of 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Note that the ^ should be in the first column of the table. Not just the column preceding where you want the sum.

Answer (score 78):

The last row of a table is `@>`
For example to get the sum for the third column in the last line, you can use the formula

```
@>$3=vsum(@2..@-1)
```

Maybe you have to adapt the `@2`, if you don't have a header line...

Answer (score 67):

Yet another possibility makes use of horizontal lines (`@I`, `@II`, etc.) which are useful anyways to structure your table:

```
| What  |    $$ |
|-------+-------|
| Ice   |  3.00 |
| Soda  |  6.49 |
| Gin   |  4.99 |
|-------+-------|
| Total | 14.48 |
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

Without a header, just let the sum start at `@0` as suggested by others already.

*Edit:*
I just saw that you wrote this yourself already in a comment to your question.

Comment: It took me a minute to understand that @I and @II refer to the horizontal rules, but I think this is the simplest way to do it if you organize your table this way.

Comment: Which keybinding should I use to set sum's result?

Comment: C-c C-c with point on the formula on the TBLFM line worked for me.

Comment: Can also use the greater-than symbol for the column, for example @>$>=vsum(@I..@II) puts the result on the last line of the last column. Brilliant!

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

`$<col_num>=<func>(@2..@-1))`

`@2` is static. It refers to the 2nd row onwards.
`@-1` refers to the second to last row.

I think this was the easiest and non-intrusive way. It preserves your column names and does not clutter up the visual space. It does not require you to address the last row. It is addressed by default.

Rows can be added/removed.
No other markers.

eg.
`#+TBLFM: $3=vmean(@2..@-1)::$4=vsum(@2..@-1))`

Sample table

```
   | Time                   | Input             | Test      | InQty |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 06:15> | Water             |           |   200 |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 07:03> |                   |           |       |
   |                        |                   |           |       |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 07:31> | Water             |           |   180 |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 09:00> | Chai              |           |   240 |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 11:30> | Chai              |           |   240 |
   | <2018-03-13 Tue 16:01> | Water             |           |    60 |
   |                        |                   |           |       |
   |------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------|
   |                        |                   |           |   920 |
   #+TBLFM: $4=vsum(@2..@-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Something which may not be apparent to a reader is the function is `vsum()` not sum()

The other thing, is that the `@2..@-1` thing, is a reference to the row-specific label for the column being summed. The `$A$1` thing in Excel is like `@1$1` so a reference to `vsum(@2..@-1)` is saying "do a sum of the values from the column, using as the row index the `@` value in the range 2, to the -1th (ie second last) row, but the column is a "given" in this so its vsum applied over `[@2$col @3$col @4$col... @-1$col]` if you try to map these concepts into Excel

Answer (score 0):

```
|  3 |
|  2 |
|  5 |
| 10 |
#+TBLFM: @4$1=vsum(@1..@-1)
```

`@1` refers to the 1st row, and `@-1` to the row preceding the one holding the formula.  That formula ignores hlines:

```
|  3 |
|  2 |
|  5 |
|----|
| 10 |
#+TBLFM: @4$1=vsum(@1..@-1)
```